# Reasons behind deleting this question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

With all due respect to @Gordon as a moderator I would like to hear **specific legitimate** reasons behind deletion of this ordinary enough question https://stackoverflow.com/q/18426674/1920232.

I can understand this question to be marked as duplicate, but I don't see any legitimate reason for it to be deleted. It's not spam, abuse or complete nonsense.

**EDIT** Interestingly enough this question is marked as duplicate of a **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133703/1920232)** which itself marked as duplicate. But for some reason the latter has not been deleted.

Comment: Does the duplicate really duplicate your question?  Does the duplicate answer your question completely, fully and satisfactorily?  If the answers to both of those questions are "yes," then why repeat the information on the site unnecessarily?  Note that you are working in the PHP tag, a tag known for people asking the same question over and over again (the dup is itself closed as a dup of another question).

Comment: @Robert - whether the dup answered his question is beside the point.  I thought there was a clear policy around here that non-identical duplicates were supposed to be left open to help drive traffic.

Comment: There's a limit to that... Duplicates can be useful when they are depicting different shades of grey.  But there's no point in having a hundred duplicates laying around that all ask exactly the same thing and point to the same original post.

Comment: They **don't** say the same thing.  The question titles are differently worded and would likely be reached by different search terms.  Why in the world is legitimate, helpful content being deleted?  Are we not trying to drive as much traffic to SO as possible?

Comment: You don't use PHP; you don't understand. If you glimpse into the terrible world of PHP on Stack Overflow, as I have, you will see the same duplicate repeated tens of times per day. It's terrible.

Comment: This question must have upward of 7,000 duplicates on Stack Overflow and any search terms that exist are likely to be amply covered. Any new dupes of this question need to be shot on sight, marinated in gasoline, and burned. That said, I do appreciate that peterm authored a fine answer to the question, even teaching a man to fish etc... maybe it needs to be undeleted just for that reason, I don't know

Comment: @notPekka I can agree with you only if 20 out of these 7000 that totaly cover the subject will be left and **all others 6980 will be deleted**. Not just delete arbitrarily now and then just if you feel like it.

Comment: @peterm the entire system of Stack Overflow relies on "arbitrary" actions (i.e. when a user sees something and flags it or casts a vote on it). Nothing wrong with that in principle.

Comment: @notPekka I have no issues with flags, voting, closing etc. They are all great because there is in place a mechanism to revert actions.  IMHO the lack of voting for undelete by other community members  when delete was made by a moderator is **wrong**.

Comment: I will defer to @doorknob, Pekka, and other php experts.  The more I learn about php the more scared I become!